# Constant as rvalue in C++(11)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Why `const int` is **not** an R-value in C++(11)? I thought that R-value was 'anything' which cannot be on the left hand side and constants fulfil that. This code fails:

```
int f(int && x) { return 100; }

void g() {
  const int x = 1;
  f(x);
}

error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&&’ from expression
of type ‘const int’
```

Comment: @Kimi though short your comment is the correct answer.

Comment: This is true, however I would speculate that for those who don't know what lvalues and rvalues "are" in C++11, this answer could be more helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how my comment was moved here, but when I said "this is true" what I was referring to was a now-deleted answer that stated "Constant has a name so it is an lvalue"

Comment: Please do not vote to close this question as being off-topic.  This is definitely on-topic for SO, and besides that it's a very good question.

Comment: BTW, "const int" is a type, not a value :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, there are three categories of expressions<sup>1</sup>:

1. those that represent objects that have an identity and cannot be moved from;
2. those that represent objects that have an identity and can be moved from;
3. those that represent objects that do not have an identity and can be moved from;

The first ones are called lvalues, the second ones are xvalues, and the third ones are prvalues. If we put lvalues and xvalues together, we have glvalues. Glvalues are all expressions that represent objects with an identity. If we put xvalues and prvalues together we have rvalues. Rvalues are all expressions that represent objects that can be moved.

The expression in question, `x`, is a glvalue: one can write `&x`, so the object clearly has an identity.

Can we move from this expression? Is this object about to expire? No, it is not. It only expires sometime after the current expression. That means it cannot be moved from. That makes it an lvalue.

All these names can be a bit confusing because lvalue and rvalue in C++ no longer mean what they meant in their C origins. The C++ meaning is completely unrelated to being on the left or right side of assignment<sup>2</sup>.

Personally, I prefer to use the terminology from [this paper](http://stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf) by Bjarne: iM-values (instead of lvalues), im-values (instead of xvalues), Im-values (instead of prvalues), i-values (instead of glvalues), and m-values (instead of rvalues). That is not the terminology that the standard uses, unfortunately.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here "have an identity" means "its address can be taken"; "can be moved from" means that it is about to expire, either due to its temporary nature, or because the programmer made that explicit in the type system by calling `std::move` or something similar.

<sup>2</sup> You can have rvalues on the left side of assignment: `std::vector<int>(17) = std::vector<int>(42)` is a valid expression, even if it is useless.

Comment: That's a defect, IMO, and should be remedied- there's no reason to permit that assignment.

Comment: @DeadMG: Write a proposal to the LWG to decorate the container's assignment operators with the `&` ref-qualifier, i.e. `Cont& operator=(Y) &;`.

Comment: @DeadMG: That could break existing code, in non-trivial ways. Even adding a keyword is carefully considered, and that causes clear compilation errors. Not going to happen, IOW.

Comment: This is a good summary IMHO, but strictly speaking, objects always have an identity. However, there are expressions that *pretend* that the object has no identity. Otherwise, you are saying that sometimes (when an lvalue refers to it) an object has an identity, and another time the same object has no identity (if the object is referred to by a prvalue). This is a contradiction: `struct A { void f() { /* lvalue */ *this; } }; int main() { A() /* prvalue */.f(); }`

Answer (score 6):

> I thought that R-value was 'anything' which cannot be on the left
>   hand side [of an assignment operaton]

That's the C++03 definition of `rvalue`, and even then its a colloquialism and not universally true.

In C++11, the definitions for `lvalue` and `rvalue` have changed somewhat.  The rules are complex, and individual situations are handled on a case-by-case basis in the Standard, but here is a general rule of thumb:

1. If you can take the address of something, it is an `lvalue`
2. If the type of an expression is an `lvalue` reference, that expression is an `lvalue`
3. If neither of the above apply, it is an `rvalue`

In your particular case, you can take the address of `x` (eg, it "has a name") and it is therefore an lvalue.

You can read more about lvalues and rvalues in C++11 in two excellent articles:

- [rvalue References Explained](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html), by Thomas Becker (blog article)
- [Universal References](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload111.pdf), by Scott Meyers (Overload #111)

Comment: I think you misunderstood Scott's article. `const int&&` always means rvalue reference. Only when deduced template type parameters are involved does the meaning of `&&` become that of "universal reference" (i.e., can be rvalue or lvalue reference).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes"  I'll re-read the article (again, this will be my 3rd time through).  In the meeantime, I'll edit out that bit.

Comment: Pay special attention to the rule of thumb he states near the start, and what words he bolded.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter type is an rvalue reference and the standard forbids initialization
 of an rvalue-reference with an lvalue of a "reference-related" type.

> 8.5.3 References [dcl.init.ref ]
>
> ...
>
> 5 ... If T1 is reference-related to T2 and the reference is an rvalue
>   reference, the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue.

Hence, the following is an error:

```
void f (long &&);

const long x = 1;
void g () { f (x); }
```

But the following is not:

```
void f (long &&);

const int x = 1;
void g () { f (x); }
```

---

So, the reason for the error is **not** simply "the initialization is not with an rvalue", but because "the initialization is with an lvalue of a reference-related type."

Answer (score 0):

In the simple words, you should be able to 'steal' the value of rvalue. This is the whole point of different treatment of rvalues. So rvalue should be unnamed-going-to-die-in-near-future-something.